# access permissions in nginx config

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

I have system structure like `/var/www/system`

What I want: allow to access to `/system/` only from 10 ips, but `/system/bills` can access anyone ?

This is possible to do with `nginx`, my virtual machine is run on Centos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.  In your server config you will just need separate location blocks for each.

For example if your server block has a root /var/www already defined then:

```
location /system {
    allow 192.168.1.1;
    allow 192.168.1.2;
    allow ...
    deny all;
}

location /system/bills {
    allow all;
}
```